Should solenoid be connected to NO or NC terminal of RF remote to retract plunger end off of edge of tiny spring-loaded door so it can snap closed?
Remote-control nestbox bird trap. End of solenoid plunger will rest on edge of the tiny, spring-loaded trap door to hold it open until remote control is used to trigger solenoid to retract, releasing door to snap closed over entrance of box. Should the solenoid be wired to the NO terminal of the RF remote receiver, or the NC terminal?

why don't you try each one? ... it makes no sense to be asking

Probably NO but you will just have to test it like @jsotola says.
